# My Evernote token fails against production even though it's been activated

Tags: evernote

My Evernote token recently got activated on production, according to Evernote support. However, when I try to use it in production via (Python) with this

```
client = EvernoteClient(token=token, sandbox=False, china=False)
```

I get this (snipped top part of stack)

```
File "/Users/derrick/Dropbox/naomi_shortlist_sheets/lib/evernote/edam/userstore/UserStore.py", line 1088, in getUserUrls
    return self.recv_getUserUrls()
File "/Users/derrick/Dropbox/naomi_shortlist_sheets/lib/evernote/edam/userstore/UserStore.py", line 1114, in recv_getUserUrls
    raise result.systemException
evernote.edam.error.ttypes.EDAMSystemException: EDAMSystemException(errorCode=8, rateLimitDuration=None, _message=u'authenticationToken')
```

When I set `sandbox=True`, it works, but then, of course, it's just Sandbox.

This would seem to imply that my token has not in fact been activated on production, but I'm wondering if there's something else going on before I contact support.